# Is $1/z$ differentiable on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The way I usually solve these kind of questions is by using the Cauchy Riemann Equations...

$h(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}$

$=\dfrac{1}{x+iy}$

$=\dfrac{1}{x+iy} \dfrac{x-iy}{x-iy}$

$=\dfrac{x-iy}{(x+iy)(x-iy)}$

$=\dfrac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$

$=\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}-\dfrac{iy}{x^2+y^2}$

Does this make $u(x,y)=\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $v(x,y)=-\dfrac{y}{x^2+y^2}$

Im a little confused with the example.. or is there a better way for me to show whether it is differentiable or not?

Comment: Why do you write $\frac{1}{x+iy}=\frac{1}x + \frac{1}{iy}$? That isn't true...

Comment: And why use the Cauchy–Riemann equations? That's way overkill, and more commonly used to show that something is *not* analytic. Try to write up the definition of derivative instead, it is instructive.

Comment: @Mathsstudent147 : if you do it your way, actually $v(x,y) = -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$, not $v(x,y) = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$.  Plus, I think Harald's suggestion is the way to go.  I am pretty sure the CR equations are equivalent to the definition of the derivative $f'(z) = \lim_{\Delta z\to 0} \frac{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)}{\Delta z}$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I have used the definition of the derivative and i've ended up with $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \dfrac{-1}{z(z+h)} =0$ is this right? Sorry i just get a little confused with the definition of the derivative?

Comment: That's fine, except the answer isn't zero. And the limit should be as $h\to0$, not $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{x+iy}\not=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{iy}.$$ 
However, 
$$
\frac{1}{x+iy}=\frac{1}{x+iy}\frac{x-iy}{x-iy}
$$

Does this help?

Comment: I have edited the question.. of course that isn't equal.. thanks :)

Comment: seems you are on your way (the way Harald proposes is probably better though)

Answer (score 0):

As for $|q|<1$ we have
$$ \frac1{1-q}=1+q+\frac {q^2}{1-q}$$
and as the last summand is $<2|q|^2$ if $|q|<\frac12$, we see that
$$ \frac1{1-q}=1+q+o(q)\quad \text{as }q\to0.$$
Thus we find that for $|h|<|z_0|$
$$ \frac1{z_0+h}=\frac1{z_0}\cdot\frac1{1-(-h/{z_0})}=\frac1{z_0} {-\frac1{z_0^2}}h+o(-h/z_0)=\frac1{z_0} \color{red}{-\frac1{z_0^2}}h+o(h),$$
which means that $z\mapsto \frac1z$ has complex derivative $-\frac1{z_0^2}$ at any $z_0\ne0$.